# 'Content Type' link not available for new content type

Tags: nodes

I have created a new content type (I can see in Content type list), but this is not available on "content >> Add Content".

Checked most parameters on creating the content type. No success.

Comment: Are you logged in as user 1? If not, check permissions so that your roles have access to create a node of the type you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Structure >> Menus >> Navigation >> list links

(/admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation)

Make sure that the content type link is enabled.